# Discord py - get channel id from new created channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**Hey guys,**

I am trying to create a little question - answer thing

So what am I trying to do?

1. react on a message in a specific channel (done)
2. create a new channel under a certain category (done)
3. get the id of the channel and send a message in this channel

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    message_id = payload.message_id
    category = guild.get_channel(766608102081822730)

    if message_id == 769082530611593216 and emoji == "":
        overwrites = {guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)}
        category = guild.get_channel(769083552209698826)
        now = datetime.now()
        date = now.strftime("%A - %d./%m./%Y")
        await category.create_text_channel(date, overwrites=overwrites)
```

**My question is - how can I get the channel id from a new created channel?**

Why do I need the ID of this new created channel?

Because I want to send a message to the channel - therefor I need the ID right?

**My second question:**

I want the channel name like a date (Monday - 10.12.2020) - discord shows the name like

> monday-10122020

okay no problem - everything is fine

But I want my bot to check if the name "monday-10122020" is already in use - **if yes it returns** - else he creates a new channel name "date" and puts it in a certain category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can't put `.` to the name of the channel names. As far as I know, the best you can do is putting `-`.

Then, when you create a channel, use a variable like this

```py
channel = await category.create_text_channel(date, overwrites=overwrites)
await channel.send('New channel created.`)
```

and send a message.

You can check the channel name before you create the channel with iterating through `category.text_channels`.

```
date = now.strftime("%A-%d-/%m-/%Y"
for channel in category.text_channels:
    if date in channel.name:
        await channel.send('This channel exist')
        return
channel = await category.create_text_channel(date, overwrites=overwrites)
await channel.send('New channel created.`)
```

So with this code, if a channel with the name `date` variable exist, it will send a message to that channel, if it doesn't exist, it'll create the channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The message to the new created channel works fine but the problem with the equal channel names is still existing :( -  I have already tried this code befor I asked my question but it didnt work

Comment: Can you try to print out `date` and the channel's name? What are the outputs?

Comment: ahh the date is - Friday-23-10-2020 - and the channel name is - friday-23-10-2020! I just used date.lower() to set everythin in lower characters. But now the remove_reaction function doesnt work anymore - but thanks for your help

Comment: Okay fixed the problem with the reaction_remove :D